# Concatenate Optional Lists

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have three Optional> which have to be combined and returned. I tried to use `Optional.map()` and `flatmap()` but was not successful.

```
public Optional<List<Entiy>> getRecords() {
    Optional<List<Entiy>> entity1 = repo.findAllByStatus("1");
    Optional<List<Entiy>> entity2 = repo.findAllByStatus("2");
    Optional<List<Entiy>> entity3 = repo.findAllByStatus("3");
    //Need to return a concatenation of entity1, 2 and 3
}
```

Any thoughts on how to do is efficiently?

Comment: Why do you want to return an `Optional`? Surely the caller would prefer an empty list in case there are no records?

Comment: @OleV.V. Exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like :

```
return Optional.of(Stream.of(entity1.orElse(new ArrayList<>()), entity2.orElse(new ArrayList<>()), entity3.orElse(new ArrayList<>()))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

or rather more readable as :

```
return Optional.of(Stream.of(entity1, entity2, entity3)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: `Collections.emptyList`

Comment: You don’t need to do everything with method references, sometimes, a lambda expression is not bad, `return Optional.of(  Stream.of(entity1, entity2, entity3) .flatMap(o -> o.map(List::stream).orElse(null)) .collect(Collectors.toList())  );`

Answer (score 3):

It gets easier when you use a stream:

```
return Stream.of(entity1, entity2, entity3)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Optional::of));
```

Important to note that this optional won't ever be empty. It will contain at least an empty list, which defeats the purpose of using optionals. When using `Collection`  types as return types, `Optional` are not really used because it's recommended to return an *empty* collection where an empty optional would be used.

So I would just change the method's return type to `List` and let the stream return an empty list when no input optional is *present*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you don’t want to return an `Optional` from your method. In case there are no records in any of the three entity lists, the caller would prefer just to have an empty list.

```
public List<Entity> getRecords() {
    return Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
            .map(repo::findAllByStatus)
            .flatMap(el -> el.map(List::stream).orElse(Stream.empty()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

A couple of the other answers use `isPresent` and `get`. They are low-level, and we don’t need them here.

We don’t absolutely need the stream operation, though. Here’s a possibility without it:

```
public List<Entity> getRecords() {
    List<Entity> concatenation = new ArrayList<>();
    repo.findAllByStatus("1").ifPresent(concatenation::addAll);
    repo.findAllByStatus("2").ifPresent(concatenation::addAll);
    repo.findAllByStatus("3").ifPresent(concatenation::addAll);
    return concatenation;
}
```